# Detecting div while clicking on its child

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple html structure

```
<aside>
  <div>
     <p>I WANT TO BE DIV</p>
  </div>
    <div>
     <p>I WANT TO BE DIV</p>
  </div>
</aside>

aside{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color:black;
}
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
```

when i click on div , i want to invoke an function for it using

```
var x= document.querySelector("aside");
x.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  if( e.target.nodeName == 'DIV'){
    alert(e.target.nodeName);
  }
},true)
```

but when i click on the text , it wont get invoked. How can i modify my code in order for it to work?

> https://jsfiddle.net/qc3ewpmz/

Comment: Your above code target will always be aside, so your condition will fail. IF you want to listen to the div, then x should query select DIV.

Comment: No, events are also triggered on child elements, and then the child is the target. this code should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem

It won't react to the text because the text is in a `p` tag and you are checking if the `nodeName` matches `DIV`.

> How can i modify my code in order for it to work?

I've added an OR case, which accomodates this.

```
var x= document.querySelector("aside");
x.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  if( e.target.nodeName == 'DIV' || e.target.nodeName == 'P'){
    alert(e.target.nodeName);
  }
},true)
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tbcbwraq/)

**Also**, i'm not quite sure why you have the whole `target.nodeName` part. I would have something as simple as below

```
var x= document.querySelector("aside"); x.addEventListener("click",function(e){

 alert("Hi there");

},true)
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zxhjnvLt/)

I would also strongly urge you to check out JQuery and it's selectors as a better alternative to this.

Comment: I understand why J.dd wants to do this: The alert should only appear if a `div` inside the `aside` is clicked, but he/ she doesn't want to add an event listener for every single `div`.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense!Somehow JQuery just seems like a much better use case here.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to test if the targets parent (`Element.parentNode`) is a `<div>`, but the probably best way is to go up the DOM tree until you reach a `DIV` or the element whith the event listener:

```
var x = document.querySelector("aside");

x.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    for (var tg = e.target; tg !== x && tg != null; tg = tg.parentNode) {
        if (tg.nodeName === 'DIV') {
            alert('You clicked on a <div> or an element inside it');
            break;
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Note that this even works on child elements of the paragraphs (e.g. a `<strong>` or `<em>`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc3ewpmz/3/)